# IE-7 image not coming on the top

Tags: css, html, position

I am showing a tool-tip `onmouseover` of a div. the tooltip is properly showing in Firefox and IE8. But in IE-7 it is coming behind the div. HTMl markup

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" id="tblEmployee">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="dvBorder" empid="1" nomineeid="21">
<img style="padding: 5px;" src="../../Images/user.jpg" alt="user">
<span class="EmpolyeeName">First Last</span><span class="EmployeeEmail">mail@amdocs.com</span></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When user mouseover on div.dvBorder the tool tip is dynamicaly created with the help of jquery function.

```
 function RollOut(result,crntDiv) {
            $(crntDiv).children('img').before(CreateElems('div', 'RollOverTip', result));
        }

function CreateElems(type,cssClass,value)
        {
            var elem = $(document.createElement(type));

            if(value != null)
                elem.text(value);

            if(cssClass!= null)
                elem.addClass(cssClass);

            return elem;
        }
```

The css class.

```
.RollOverTip
{
    background-image: url("/Images/screen2-rollover-tooltip.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Calibri Regular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    height: 199px;
    line-height: 20pt;
    margin-left: 385px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 474px;
    z-index: 90000;
    padding:34px;
}

.dvBorder
{
    background-image: url(/Images/screen2-button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 125px;
    width: 400px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Is it a problem with the css , since it is working in IE-8,FF.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding z-index to your .dvBorder class:

```
.dvBorder
{
    background-image: url(/Images/screen2-button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 125px;
    width: 400px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index:0; /* If this doesn't work, try -1 */
}
```

Comment: i want rollovertip div to be coing over dvborder

Comment: I know that's what you want... if you give .RollerOverTip a z-index of 9000, and a .dvBorder a z-index, it basically sets the "ground" for it. Try it and let me know what happens, either that or post up a live link or fiddle.

Comment: if it is set to -1 than no image comes up on mouseover . If it is set to 1 the behavior is same means no change image comes behind it

Comment: I would try getting rid of the table, tbody, tr, td's (anything associated with the table). Work w/ the bare minimum elements. It could either be that the table is interfering somehow, or html elements aren't nested correctly for z-index to work properly.